# Which is the mathematical theory that talks about these structures?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let's define $\sigma(n)$ as the sum of the digits of the integer $n$ modulo $9$, having posed that $\sigma(9) = 9$.

Now consider 2 number $a$ and $b$ in the set $\{1, \cdots, 9\}$. Which is the value of $\sigma{(ab)}$?
Starting from this problem, one can imagine to build a ``pythagorean table'' for $\sigma(ab)$. That is:

$$ 
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
   &   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
 1 &   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 2 &   & 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9 \\
 3 &   & 3 & 6 & 9 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 3 & 6 & 9 \\
 4 &   & 4 & 8 & 3 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 1 & 5 & 9 \\
 5 &   & 5 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 7 & 3 & 8 & 4 & 9 \\
 6 &   & 6 & 3 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 9 \\
 7 &   & 7 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 9 \\
 8 &   & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 9 \\
 9 &   & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 \\
\end{array}
$$
This is the first structure I'm looking for the right mathematical theory. In particular, I think it's something like an algebra on the set $\{1, \cdots, 9\}$, with the following product:
$$ a \times b = \sigma(ab)$$

Now, what can we say about the ``new'' product when we use $2$-digits numbers? 
Let's $n = 10a + b$ and $m = 10c + d$, with $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are number in the set $\{1, \cdots, 9\}$. Then:
$$nm = 100ac + 10(b+d) + bd$$
At this point, we have to state that $\sigma(10^k a) = \sigma(a)$ (multiplying $a$ by a power of $10$, we are only adding ''0''s at the end of the number which do not give any contribution to $\sigma$). Hence:
$$\sigma(nm) = \sigma(\sigma(ac) + \sigma(b+d) + \sigma(bd)) = \sigma \left((a \times c) + \sigma(b+d) + (b \times d) \right)$$

In general, if $n = \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} 10^i n_i$ and $m = \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} 10^i m_i$, then:

$$\sigma(nm) = \sigma\left(\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}10^{i+j}n_i m_j\right) = \sigma\left(\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} (n_i \times m_j)\right)$$

In a certain way, I generalize the product $\times$ for any integers $n$ and $M$ as follows:

$$ n \times m = \sigma\left(\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} (n_i \times m_j)\right)$$

This is the last structure I'm facing with. Is there some one that ever seen this? Are there some theoretical results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing multiplication $\pmod 9$, where you only care about the remainder on division by $9$.  Usually one uses $0$ instead of $9$, but that is not important.  You can also add $\pmod 9$, things have additive inverses, and multiplication distributes over addition.  This makes it the ring $\Bbb {Z/9Z}$  This works with any modulus.  If the modulus is prime, you get a field, because all the elements (except $0$) have a multiplicative inverse and you can divide as well.  You might read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

Comment: good point! however, can you say me something about operator $\sigma$ within rings theory?

Comment: Your operator $\sigma$ returns the remainder on division by $9$, sometimes called the digital root.  It takes you from $\Bbb Z$ to one of the nine elements of $\Bbb {Z/9Z}$, so is not part of the ring.

Answer (score 1):

Your $\sigma(n)$ is just the remainder when $n$ is divided by $9$ (except that you write "$9$" rather than "$0$" when $n>0$, but that could be considered just a matter of notation, as modulo $9$, we see that $0$ and $9$ are equivalent). So you have results like $\sigma(nm)\equiv\sigma(n)\sigma(m)$ and $\sigma(n+m)\equiv\sigma(n)+\sigma(m)$, where $\equiv$ means congruence modulo $9$ (or equality in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$). See [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

In particular, your notation $\times$ seems redundant: your $a\times b$ (or $n \times m$) means nothing other than $\sigma(ab)$ (or $\sigma(nm)$), so your last equation could well be written $\sigma(nm)=\sigma(\sum_{i,j}n_im_j)$ or be written as $n \times m \equiv \sum_{i, j} n_i \times m_j$.

The [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution) that you see in the sums above is simply one that comes from the definition of multiplication in terms of digits.

Comment: (This is redundant with Ross's answer, but I had started typing it as a comment and then it wouldn't fit so had to move it to an answer.)

Comment: good point to you too! But now the question is quite the same I posed to Ross: can you say me something more about operator σ and its properties?

Comment: @the_candyman: If you work in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$, namely the ring that identifies every integer with its remainder modulo $9$, then $\sigma$ is just the identity operator: $\sigma(n) \equiv n$. So you can make up infinitely many "properties" of $\sigma$: that $\sigma(a + b + c) = \sigma(a) + \sigma(b) + \sigma(c)$, that $\sigma(abc) = \sigma(a)\sigma(b)\sigma(c)$, that $\sigma(a^n) = \sigma(a)^n$, and so on. There is nothing special to say about $\sigma$, because in this ring, it is the identity function.

Comment: @the_candyman: To elaborate: in this ring, when you apply $\sigma$ to a number, you don't change that number. So the study of properties of $\sigma$ is more properly the study of the ring itself, which is precisely what [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) is.

Comment: Ok, you have been really clear! Thank you very much!